# Battling with a sulfur-based Djinn

Tags: chemistry

Finishing a story which tangentially features a Djinn who is quickly / easily dispatched by a scientist through a feat of chemistry wizardry.

If one were trying to neutralize a sulfur-based entity, do any solutions come to mind?  Something that potentially could be injected into the Djinn, or a gas?  Or other clever way of dispatching it?

Comment: It would definitely help if you described your creature. Sulfur-based can mean anything between "this thing has a higher amount of sulfur in the body than normal" to "this thing is made from hardened sulfur, breathe sulfure, is sulfur". The same can be said about Djinns, which have various representations, and I'm not including variants like Ifrits, Genies...

Comment: It looks like you're asking about the actions of a character, in response to an underdefined scenario. Questions about the actions of individuals aren't about establishing the facts of a world and are off topic for this site.

Comment: Good point Tortliena, I suppose I wanted to think about the Djinn as actually being non-Carbon based.  So, a truly Sulfur-based organism.  And I see what you're saying sphennings re: the scope of my question, I can assure you there's a lot of world building happening with this project so I'll share my future inquiries in that spirit of worlds over inidividual actions.  But the feedback here has been incredibly helpful nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

## Booze

The other answers are reasonable - cesium will give almost anything a bad day, as will bullets.  But I'm going to impose a couple of extra restrictions to make it entertaining:

1. The attack should be more dangerous to jinn than human
2. Jinn are, in some tellings, derived from fire and air, so I am *not* going to post a picture of a sulfur eruption and say set a match.  Instead, I'll assume the jinn can be heated by its own actions or externally without any direct harm.

Given these two things, Ryan Landels' approach of using carbon disulfide is on the right track.  The jinn is made out of sulfur and I'm not going to try to react the whole thing with some toxic chemical.  Instead, I want to *catalytically* influence which *[allotropes of sulfur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_sulfur)* are being pumped back and forth within whatever is vaguely equivalent to cardiovascular or respiratory systems.  Now, that Wikipedia article I just linked above comes up as a hit for carbon disulfide because the chemical can shift sulfur from its normal allotropes into a form called "nacreous sulfur"; but it also says that chilling a solution of sulfur in ethyl alcohol will do it.  (They cite Greenwood, Norman N.; Earnshaw, Alan (1997). Chemistry of the Elements (2nd ed.). Butterworth-Heinemann. ISBN 0080379419. page 655, and if you write a proper story going this way that hinges on this 'clever solution' you probably ought to follow up that source and verify).

The scenario I have in mind is that the jinn is burning its sulfur with air in a controlled fashion, making it scalding hot to the touch and a dangerous opponent.  You throw the ethanol on it and cause nacreous patches to break out wherever it lands, which disperse and spread through its body with horrific effect.

Additionally, there is a certain closure in using ethanol to fight a legendary creature known from Islamic sources.  I don't know much about the religion, but it seems to check out; see: "[There is a remedy for every malady...](https://themuslimahnetwork.com/sunnah-remedies/sunnah-remedies-table/)"

Comment: This is brilliant!  In this particular scenario, the Djinn is using its shapeshifting abilities to appear in a human shell, but its hot core is underneath... so, perhaps an injection of ethanol into its internal system would spread the nacreous patches throughout its internal structure.  And for the purposes of the story this symbolic tie-in with alcohol is awesome!!  Thank you for your thoughtful and detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

Bullets do damage because of physics, not because of chemistry. You want a bullet to pierce into the target body, possibly fragment and tumble while inside it, so that it can wreak havoc and kill.

In normal bullets lead is usually mixed with antimony to harden it, else it would splat against the bones rather than crushing them.

Bullet induced poisoning would normally take much longer. But if silver is toxic for your creature, why not? It's entirely up to you.

Comment: I thought you were going in the direction of "bullets do damage. Just shoot the darn thing." Very much an image of Indiana Jones gun-at-a-sword-fight scene. Works for "easily dispatched'!

Comment: Yeah my original post wasn't very clear!  Thanks for your reply though.  I tried to be clearer in my edit of the post.  I think the spirit of it is very much Indi pulling out his gun and making short work of a threatening foe, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Gibbs free energy of formation is a measure of how much energy is released by forming the compound.  The larger the energy release gives the stabler the compound.  The universe doesn't merely tend, but tries strenuously to achieve the lowest energy state, that is to say the stablest and most imobile form.

If I asked what you would do with a Djinn made of pure oxygen, you could think of a hundred things.  Sulfur is the same group as Oxygen, which means it tries to act quite a bit like oxygen.

There is a chemistry acronym: Oil Rig, that stands for "oxidation is loss, reduction is gain".  So when you think of Oxygen, a common oxidizer, the reaction is called oxidation, and it is modeled as an electron donor.  You want something that is very hungry for electrons to bind with it.  Hydrogen likes electrons, as do any of the group 1A and group 2A elements.  The farther you go down on the group 1A, the hungrier they are.

If you put refined metallic cesium in water it will explode as the cesium rips the oxygen out of the water molecules.  It's quite dangerous.  Less dangerous elements include Sodium, and Potassium which are used for class demonstrations because of the difference between a fizz and a pop, good showmanship can lead to decent teaching.

I think metallic potassium would be common, accessible, and damaging for a sulfur-based organism.  There are a multitude of things that could also work including Cadmium, Beryllium, Barium, as oxidizers.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4pQz3TC0Jo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmaZdEq-Xzs

Answer (score 0):

You could chuck some carbon disulfide do dissolve it. Sulfur dissolves into carbon disulfide, but is flammable and volatile, so maybe invent some sort of carbon disulfide hose(?)